# Iterated integral over a region by vertical and horizontal cross-sections: what's the conceptual difference?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have a problem that instructs me to solve an iterated integral over a region, $R$, using vertical and horizontal cross-sections.

I understand that, by Fubini's theorem, the order of integration does not matter for the final answer. However, changing the order of integration may make the problem easier to integrate.

My question is regarding the difference between the concepts of integrating over vertical and horizontal cross-sections of a region: Although they should both produce the same final answer, what is the intuitive difference? For instance, when we integrate over a vertical cross section, we must first integrate with respect to $y$ and then with respect to $x$. When we integrate over a horizontal cross section, we must first integrate with respect to $x$ and then with respect to $y$. Why is there this difference? Conceptually, I do not understand what the difference is between these and why the order of integration is interchanged.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this concept for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both integrals compute the volume under the graph of a function $z = f(x,y)$. Think of the iterated integrals as an application of the "volume by slices" idea: adding up the volumes of thin slabs (more technically, integrating cross-sectional area).

For the integral $\iint f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$, you are first fixing $y$, and integrating over $x$, computing the cross-sectional area $A(y)$ at that fixed value of $y$. So this integral computes the volume "by slices", by integrating $\int A(y) \, dy$.

Similarly, for $\iint f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$, you are first computing the cross-sectional area $A(x)$ at each fixed value of $x$, and then integrating $A(x)$ to get the volume.

So the difference, conceptually, is the direction of the "slabs" or "slices" that you are using to compute the volume.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your post has clarified much of the concept. However, I have a couple of more questions, if it wouldn't be too much trouble: When you say we "fix" $x$ or $y$, how is this represented during this process? How do we represent the "fixed" variables when calculating area?

Comment: When doing iterated integrals, at each stage, you treat all other variables as constants. For example, if you do $\iint f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$, then the first integral treats $y$ as constant. That is what I mean by "fixed". Geometrically, the result of this first integral gives the function $A(y)$ of $y$ alone, as I mentioned above, and you can image that for each $y$, $A(y)$ is the area under the graph of the cross section of the surface with the plane $y=\mathrm{const}$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically changing integration over vertical and horizontal cross-sections of a region doesn't different in most cases, and this interchanging between them just easier them for integration. Picture below shows a region between two curves $y=2x^2-1$ and $4y=x^2-6x+1$.
[image]

Integrating over this region can be written like
$$\int_0^1\int_1^3 f(x,y)\,\text{dy}\text{dx}+\int_1^2\int_{down_1}^{up_1} f(x,y)\,\text{dy}\text{dx}+\int_2^3\int_{down_2}^{up_2}  f(x,y)\,\text{dy}\text{dx}$$
these might be a little hard to evaluate (for me) but someone can take a horizontal cross-section as shown below

[image]

this is better for calculation and I write the integral so
$$\int_1^2\int_0^{3-\sqrt{8-4y}} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy+\int_2^3\int_0^{3-\sqrt{y-2}} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy $$
which makes a little better. For instance if we want to find the area of this region, 
take $f=1$ and we write
‎\begin{eqnarray*}‎
‎R &=& \int\!\!\int_R\,dx dy  \\‎
‎ &=& \int_1^2\int_0^{3-\sqrt{8-4y}}\,dx\,dy+\int_2^3\int_0^{3-\sqrt{y-2}}\,dx\,dy \\‎
‎ &=& \int_1^2(3-\sqrt{8-4y})\,dy+\int_2^3(3-\sqrt{y-2})\,dy\\‎
‎ &=& 4‎
‎\end{eqnarray*}‎